# Anna? - No, not Anna

Tags: meaning-in-context

Could you explain what "No, not Anna" means?
If I am right, "No" means that Anna can't go to the party but what about "not Anna"?

> - Did you invite guests to our party on Saturday? ... Anna?
> - No, not Anna. She said she didn’t like parties and couldn’t dance.

PS. Before Anna there was some phrases about another man. There is only "No".

> - What about Stephen?
> - No. He said he had a few days’ holiday and (he) was going to Italy.

I don't understand the difference.

TIA

Comment: You are asking if Anna has been invited to the party and the answer is that Anna wasn't invited because she doesn't like parties and can't dance.

Answer (score 1):

It's simply just a case of the speaker explaining their statement of "no".

Just saying "yes" or "no" to a question (in fact, being *monosyllabic* in general) can be considered rude. The shortest contradictory statements tend to be along the lines of "*no it isn't*" rather than just "*no*".

Another reason for adding the detail is to qualify exactly what you are saying "no" to. Taking your example, if you asked "can I invite Anna?" and receive the answer "no", it wouldn't be clear if the host was against inviting Anna personally of just against any additional guests in general. By saying "no, not Anna" it makes it very clear this is specifically about Anna.

Comment: Before that there was about another man: - What about Stephen? - No. He said he had a few days’ holiday and (he) was going to Italy.

Comment: As you see only "No."

Comment: There is no difference meaningwise. The speaker just chooses to name Anna and not Stephen.